# aspx OnSaveStateComplete equivalent on usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, code-behind

In my aspx I have:

```
protected override void OnSaveStateComplete(EventArgs e)
{
    int pagecount = rvReports.LocalReport.GetTotalPages();
}
```

no I want to be able to do the same thing in my usercontrol(ascx) codebehind, I tried

```
protected virtual void OnSaveStateComplete(EventArgs e)
{
    int pagecount = rvReports.LocalReport.GetTotalPages();
}
```

but it doesn't do anything, for ascx should I be using something else instead of OnSaveStateComplete?